# Accessing Child Components in lightning-input DOM element

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I am trying to populate the  field that is nested within an aura  component using DOM elements.

I am able to access the parent  with `document.getElementsByTagName`; however, I cannot access the child  component that is nested in the parent lightning-input. After looking into the documentation, it mentions that we cannot use document or window properties to query these nested DOM elements, but instead, we need to use the template as the root target.

**Reference** 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_dom_work

Is it possible to view the nested input tags and modify the text within it?

**Example Format**

```
<div>
    <lightning-input>
        <input id="input-0">
    </lightning-input>
</div>
```

For more context, the input tag acts as a login field, where I am looking to populate the field when a button is pressed externally (within a mobile app).

Comment: From parent component, you need to call a method on child who has the components in its own DOM, in child's method you can get the fields and return back to parent. I haven't seen inputs nested inside `lightning-input` tag, base input component is an alternative to regular HTML inputs with LWC related features. If you want to use input, use it instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response Raul. 

I am currently using a custom-built lightning page which uses the nested input fields. I also haven't seen input fields nested in the lightning-input but I will connect with my team to see if we can work around this issue. 

I am mostly looking to modify the nested input rather than fetching it's value, but we will look into modifying the lightning page in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest input fields, neither in LWC or even normal HTML. The reason why this doesn't work is because `lightning-input` doesn't have a default slot. Even getting the `input` element wouldn't set the `lightning-input` value, as that's a separate input field.

All that said, you can just set the value directly:

```
handleClick(event) {
  this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value = 'Hello World!';
}
```

You can give the element some unique attribute if you need to retrieve it amongst several such fields on the page, such as:

```
<lightning-input name="username"></lightning-input>
```

...

```
const input = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input[name=username]');
input.value = 'Hello World!';
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. 

I am currently using a custom-built lightning page which uses the nested input fields. I also haven't seen input fields nested in the lightning-input but I will connect with my team to see if we can work around this issue. 

I have applied the same solution you suggested; however, the validations do not detect the injected text, which is why I was looking into injecting this information into the nested input field as well.

Comment: @KChelvan you can call reportValidity on the element afterwards to report any errors.